# Ubuntu 13.04 - Black screen with unresponsive cursor

Tags: unity, boot, grub2, 13.04

Few days ago I installed ubuntu 13.04 on a new machine without big issues.
Today, after the boot, I have this situation:

- grub correctly loaded and normal boot
- normal purple screen with red dots
- instead of normal login screen I have a black screen with an almost unresponsive mouse pointer and keyboard (they are really slow and they react with a latency of a couple of seconds)
- Hitting multiple times Ctrl+Alt+F1 I can reach a console and there operate normally (no latency anymore)
- I tried to restore the desktop environment giving unity to the console but it cannot start.

**The only "suspect" actions that I could have done yesterday are an upgrade from the repositories and maybe, having left a usb-key plugged.**

After a lot of trial-and-error, the only workaround that I found effective is to launch ubuntu in recovery mode and then, from the list, select the first field: recover normal boot (or something similar). I really cannot understand why in this way stuffs are working fine.

Do you have any idea of what the heck is going on?
Thanks a lot in advance :D

Comment: Could be many things. I've personally been having problems with kernel updates not installing correctly (causing something similar to what you describe). When I get into tty terminal, I try update & upgrade and `sudo apt-get install -f`. Another few restarts...

Comment: I had a similar problem I created a bootable 13.04 usb stick using unetbootin and after a successful install. I then rebooted and I had no keyboard no mouse on start-up, or my system would not boot at all and it would get stuck on booting the usb drivers. I re-made a new bootable usb directly in ubuntu following these instructions and reinstalled and everything worked. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu Old versions of unetbootin may not be copying files over again