# Permission issues causes Unity Segmentation fault

Tags: unity, ati, multiple-monitors, segmentation-fault, policykit

I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and I can boot to the unity-greeter and login just fine, but after login I just get a black screen with a cursor. I have tried following

- http://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI
- http://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver
- and the manual install of the downloaded AMD drivers. All have the same affect.

Also I have read

- [Black screen after login with cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297112/black-screen-after-login-with-cursor?rq=1)
- [I get a black screen after logging in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259762/i-get-a-black-screen-after-logging-in)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/347491/ubuntu-13-04-black-screen-after-login
- [Ubuntu 13.10 - Black screen after login session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361004/ubuntu-13-10-black-screen-after-login-session)
- [Ubuntu 13.04 - Black screen with unresponsive cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293048/ubuntu-13-04-black-screen-with-unresponsive-cursor?rq=1)
- [Upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 Problem - Boots into Blank Black Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289926/upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-04-problem-boots-into-blank-black-screen?rq=1)

All of which were no further help then the two support articles about ATI drivers

So I switched back to the default drivers and went a little further into debugging, when I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login and try `unity --debug >  unity_start.log` then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> the screen stays black with a cursor and when I switch back <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> the contents of the log output are http://pastebin.com/rdQG4Hb0

However when I try
`sudo unity --debug >  unity_start_root.log` then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, unity starts and the output of the log is http://pastebin.com/Yv4RD2j7

The fact that it starts as root tells be it is either a permissions issue of some required file or there is some setting that is specific to my user that is causing the `SIGSEGV`.

So to narrow this down I activated the guest account and tried to login and got the same black screens with only a mouse cursor, so this tells me that it is not a configuration issue, but a permissions issue, so how do I narrow down which file has the wrong permissions? Also is there anything further that may help debug this issue?

Ok after a few more hours of googling I found that if I add myself to the video group I can login and see the desktop, but there are lots of other permission related issues, so I am thinking something went wonky with PolicyKit during the upgrade, is there a way to reset PolicyKit settings for a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to fix this I had manually modified several files in /etc/pam.d so I created files in /usr/share/pam-configs that contained the custom modifications and ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libpam-runtime`

Now when I login all permissions work properly and I see no errors on startup

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I just fixed it. (kind of)
My solution (so you can boot back to GUI) (don't know if it really was this or it was a lot of thing together):

- open TTY (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) to type the commands.
- make sure the radeon open-source drivers are installed.
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver
- delete all the fglrx drivers:
  I first tried: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx 
  and later tried this:
  `sudo apt-get remove fglrx*`

after that I could reboot and login.

OPTIONAL: if you have login loop (type password and is accepted it will re-ask it):
(make backup of file)
`mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.old`
and retry to login.

any question, just ask.

cause: I think because old drivers (fglrx) are not supported, so replaced them with supported open-source drivers.

Comment: This did not fix the issue for me. I had to add my user to the video group to get Unity to stop Seg Faulting, and now I see alot of other permission issues